# JOOQ 3.17.x - How can I call batch methods with R2DBC?

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq, r2dbc

I learned JOOQ with R2DBC cannot call `.execute()`, instead it can call something like `.asFlow().toList()` to get a SELECT result.

However, batch methods such as `batchUpdate` doesn't seem to support that way. The following code causes an error below.

```kotlin
batchUpdate(myecords).execute()
```

```
Attempt to execute a blocking method (e.g. Query.execute() or ResultQuery.fetch()) when only an R2BDC ConnectionFactory was configured. jOOQ's RowCountQuery and ResultQuery extend Publisher, which allows for reactive streams implementations to subscribe to the results of a jOOQ query. Simply embed your query in the stream, e.g. using Flux.from(query). See also: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/reactive-fetching/
```

Can we even call batch methods with R2DBC? Thanks.